# How could i just make displacement from high poly mesh to low poly?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, texture-baking, displacement

[image]

I have an experience about baking displacement before but not like this i want to know how to create displacement texture form right side mesh to left side mesh could i do that or not?

Comment: You could bake the normals of the high poly and use the normal map on the low-poly

Comment: @moonboots thank i will try to bake it!

Comment: Also don't forget to shade smooth the low-poly, and if it's not enough, give it a Subdivision Surface modifier